# How to disable `no implicit any` notification with tsserver?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsserver

Here is sample typescript code:

```js
function test(v) {
    console.log("Test: ", v);
}
test(123)
```

With the next `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true
    },
}
```

I got next diagnostic error: `7006 Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type` which is totally fine.
I want to remove this error message. So I add `noImplicitAny: false` to `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
}
```

But instead of being removed it become an `INFO` message with code 7044:

```
7044 Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
```

How can I totally remove all messages with implicit `any`? The actual problem is that I need to work with very old and dirty project, where I got tons of this warnings just after loading my IDE.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to hide that warning completely.